# Squish text with CSS transform, but affect only individual characters

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to squish text using a CSS transform, but as you can see in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dyoLjota/1/), it also squishes the perceived box surrounding the text (this is difficult for me to describe, not sure if there are terms for what I'm trying to say). I've also tried setting the width to be 125% with a left margin of -12.5% to compensate, but this causes layout problems for me elsewhere even though it visibly fixes the problem. I don't want to squish the entire "box" as this messes with other things on my site, just the individual characters...is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
h1 {        transform:  scale(.8,1);
-webkit-transform:  scale(.8,1);
-moz-   transform:  scale(.8,1);
-ms-    transform:  scale(.8,1);
-o-     transform:  scale(.8,1);
margin:0;padding:0;}

<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque varius, ligula non laoreet ultricies, libero turpis gravida neque, nec malesuada dui metus sit amet quam.</h1>
```

Comment: You can add a span to the character that needs the style and style it that way

Comment: I need to style all the characters though so it would be really impractical unless there was some lightweight way to automate this with javascript or jquery (?)

Comment: Yes very very impractical but possible, if you have some kind of a pattern as to which character to target then maybe you can use js to do it